# Failed lambda and SQS retry interval - Clarification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a simple SQS with Lambda attached to it.

In the lambda - I do this :

- Ping an external HTTP endpoint
- **Deliberately** fail the message by throwing an exception. ( because I want to test the retry mechanism)

Here are the SQS settings :

[image]

And the DLQ settings :

[image]

But when I see the HTTP Endpoint Pings, I see this :

[image]

So the retry times **between each attempt** are:

0:35
2:25
2:59
3:00
3:01

**Questions**

- 1 - Why are those delays like this?
  I thought that when a Lambda fails to process the message, it waits for the visibility timeout to end and then -  another consumer can consume it. If so, why do I see delays less than `3 min`?
- 2 - Why there were `6` invocations when I explicitly set `Max Receives` = `5`?

Comment: Are you submitting only one message to the sqs? Also, the answer to Q1 is that visibility timeout persists.

Comment: @Marcin Yes. Im submitting only one message to SQS. Also , I didn't understand your statement : _visibility timeout persists._. if so , then why do I see 30 sec delay where it says 3 min visibility timeout ?

Comment: I see. The 3 minutes is because your visibility timeout is 3 minutes. So lambda has to wait 3 minutes before your message becomes visible again. 30 seconds or 2 minutes is interesting, indeed.

Comment: Any chance there is more than one message on the queue?

Comment: @RetoAebersold , No. I've checked.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but for me it all works as expected. The interval between all invocations is 3 minutes, and there are 5  of them. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/D6J6iNs.png). I think you should double check your testing setup.

Comment: @Marcin I will add messageId to the HttpEndpoint. BTW im using the C# SDK

Comment: I setup everything in AWS console for my tests.

Comment: me 2 @Marcin . im just sayng that my lambda is c#

Comment: I used python lambda. Try simpler setup. Just check in CloudWatch Logs for timestamps. Don't need any http endpoints to get the timestamps.

Comment: @Marcin I found the problem. AWS doesn't consider immediatly the changes in visibility timeout. try this : set  visibility to 10 sec(!)....see the interval..... should be 10 sec. now change to 3 min(!) ......push a message , you will see : 10sec ,30 sec.... and in the end : 3 min delay.

so when you change visibility , it is not immediatly takes place. try it.

Comment: So in your question, you were changing the timeout? It was not 3 minutes like on the first screenshot?

Comment: @Marcin at first it was 30 sec  . but when I changed it ( the organization askedme to change it) to 6 times the lambda timeout `( 6 * 30 sec = 180 sec = 3 min)` to 3 min , I saw those times that in the questions. and i didnt understand why am i seeing meesages in less than a 3 min window

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you want you can add answer to your question with your findings. Alternatively, I could add it, but I would only be able to write that it worked fine for me with screenshot from comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the symptom why :

at first it was 30 sec . but when I changed it ( the organization asked me to change it) to 6 times the lambda's timeout `( 6 * 30 sec = 180 sec = 3 min)` to `3 min` , I saw those times that I've mentioned in the questions. And I didnt understand why am I seeing messages in less than a `3 min` window